# pick value from one table with the value in between another table's two variable

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, t1 and t2

```
t1
ID  P     CODE
3   11     19
5   5      118
8   Null   212
6   8      992

t2
ID  c1  C2
3   1   99  
3   100 199
3   200 299
5   500 999
```

How do I select all columns of t2 and addition column with value P, where t1.code between c1 and c2
Like

```
ID  c1  C2   p
3   1   99   11
3   100 199  5
3   200 299  Null
5   500 999  8
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you intend that that t1.ID = t2.id? If so then the first couple answers should do it. Otherwise you wind up with something wierd like: SELECT t1.p,t2.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON CODE BETWEEN c1 AND  c2

Comment: @user3362749 - I've rolled back your change - your edit made the data unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*,
       (select t1.p
        from t1
        where t1.code between t2.c1 and t2.c2
        limit 1
       ) as p
from t2;
```

You can also do this with a `join`.  The correlated subquery will return only one value if there are multiple matches.  Note this uses `limit`, this functionality is available in almost all databases but might have different names.

If the issue of multiple matches isn't a big deal, you can phrase this as a `join`:

```
select t2.*, t1.p
from t2 left outer join
     t1
     on t1.code between t2.c1 and t2.c2;
```

Comment: need to add another join condition on ID

Comment: @CharlesBretana . . . I don't see why that would help answer the question.

Comment: Gordon, I might be wrong, but I assumed he wanted to look into t1 for the specific row tied to the ID of each row he is examining in t2.  But on further examination, the ranges of value pairs (c1, c2) in t2 are also unique.   which confuses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If Id is unique in T1,

```
Select t2.Id, t2.C1, t2.C2, t1.p      
From t2 left Join t1
    On t1.Id = t2.Id
       And t1.code between t2.c1 and t2.c2
```